# Symmetric difference set operation in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, set

I'm using Dart `Set`s for quick operations on collections, and the need for doing the symmetric difference between two sets has cropped up. The `Set`-class has a lot of common set-operations, but I cannot see that it has the symmetric difference-operation. Does anyone know if it exists in Dart or if it must be implemented 'by hand'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I'm using now is to implement symmetric difference by using union and differences like so:

```dart
Set<T> symmetricDifference<T>(Set<T> set1, Set<T> set2) {
  return set1.difference(set2).union(set2.difference(set1));
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties

It seems to be working well, but if there's a more idiomatic way of doing it I'm all ears!

Comment: Yes, you'll need to implement it yourself.  This way (or one of the other ways to express it, such as `set1.union(set2).difference(set1.intersection(set2))` is how it would be implemented anyway.